# Unable to resolve service for type 'Shared.Core.Enums.DatabaseType' while attempting to activate 'Shared.Infrastructure.Dapper.SqlDapperClient'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-7.0

I have following setup for .NET 7 web api with code as mentioned below :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IFruitDecisionMaker, FruitDecisionMaker>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IMainProvider, MainProvider>();
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        var configuration = builder.Configuration;
        var app = builder.Build();
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
}

public enum FruitType
{
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Banana,
    Mango
}

public interface IFruitDecisionMaker
{
    int TestMethod(int a, int b);
}

public sealed class FruitDecisionMaker : IFruitDecisionMaker
{
    private FruitType selectedFruit;
    // Constructor taking the custom enum as a parameter
    public FruitDecisionMaker(FruitType fruit)
    {
        selectedFruit = fruit;
    }

    // Method to make a decision based on the selected fruit
    public string MakeDecision()
    {
        switch (selectedFruit)
        {
            case FruitType.Apple:
                return "Let's make apple pie!";
            case FruitType.Orange:
                return "Let's have some orange juice!";
            case FruitType.Banana:
                return "Time for a banana smoothie!";
            case FruitType.Mango:
                return "Mangoes are in season, let's enjoy them!";
            default:
                return "Invalid fruit selection.";
        }
    }

    public int TestMethod(int a, int b) => a + b;
}

public interface IMainProvider
{
    IFruitDecisionMaker FruitDecisionMaker { get; }
}

public sealed class MainProvider : IMainProvider
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IFruitDecisionMaker> _lazyFruitDecisionMaker;
    public MainProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, FruitType fruitType)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        _lazyFruitDecisionMaker = GetInstance<IFruitDecisionMaker>(fruitType);
    }

    private Lazy<T> GetInstance<T>(FruitType fruitType) => new Lazy<T>(_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>());
    public IFruitDecisionMaker FruitDecisionMaker => _lazyFruitDecisionMaker.Value;
}

[Route("api/test/[action]")]
public class TestController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly ITestRepository _testRepository;
    public TestController(ITestRepository testRepository)
    {
        _testRepository = testRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetDataAsync))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var res = await _testRepository.GetDetailsAsync(cancellationToken);
        return Ok(res);
    }
}

public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
    private readonly IMainProvider _mainProvider;
    public TestRepository(IMainProvider mainProvider)
    {
        _mainProvider = mainProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainProvider));
    }

    public async Task GetDetailsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var res = await _mainProvider.FruitDecisionMaker.TestMethod(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (res == null)
            throw new Exception("Not Data Found!");
        return res;
    }
}

public interface ITestRepository
{
    Task GetDetailsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
}
```

On running the above code I am getting the below error :

> System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Shared.Core.Abstractions.Common.IMainProvider Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Shared.Infrastructure.Services.Common.MainProvider': Unable to resolve service for type 'Shared.Core.Enums.FruitType' while attempting to activate 'Shared.Infrastructure.Services.Common.MainProvider'.)
> C:\Test\bin\Debug\net7.0\TestAPI.exe (process 16468) exited with code 0.
> To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
> Press any key to close this window . . .

Comment: Can you reduce and simplify the posted code to the problem at hand by transforming it into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thanks @Steven for your response. I tried to post all the details to give a complete idea of the issue and get a solution to fix it. Any help on this request is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Santosh, I sure want to help you, but would mind reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instruction closely to understand what a minimal, reproducible example (MRE) is. For instance, I think `SqlDapperClient` contains many dependencies that are irrelevant to the problem? But I'm not sure, but you'll find out when building an MRE. Your code contains a `AddService` method, but nowhere is it called. Should it be called? Your MRE should be an example that is *complete*, as in: we should be able to paste your code in our IDE and run it.

Comment: Thanks @Steven for your suggestion. I have updated the code to minimal, reproducible example (MRE) setup now. Can you please help me here.

Comment: You're coming closer. I tried running your code locally, but it doesn't compile, but I now -hopefully- have a better understanding on what you are trying to achieve. The exception states that you didn't register `FruitType`. Try adding the following line to your DI Configuration: `builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(FruitType), FruitType.Apple);` and see if that fixed the problem.

Comment: To add to Reece's answer, when you move to dependency injection from more traditional ways of creating objects, you have to leave behind the idea of instantiating a class with its 'settings'. The constructor arguments become a list of other services/dependencies it needs to perform its role. Per-instance properties need to be configured another way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing here is because the service provider cannot provide a `FruitType` to the constructor of the `MainProvider`. This is because a `FruitType` has not been configured - though I believe an enum cannot be configured as a service in the collection.

As the `MainProvider` requires a `FruitType` to be configured, to make a decision, I would implement another way to set the fruit type in the provider. Possible a `ConfigureFruitType(FruitType)` method on the provider which can be called from somewhere.

Alternatively, when configuring the `MainProvider` you could use the following code to provide the fruit type when configuring the service:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMainProvider>(serviceProvider => 
{
   return new MainProvider(serviceProvider, FruitType.Apple);
});
```

Which will configure the `MainProvider`, with "Apple" as the fruit type.